# What is the cardinality of the union of uncountable sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

If a set U is the union of all the uncountable sets (open intervals), then what is the cardinality of U?
And how to prove that?

Comment: U is the countably union of many uncountable sets.

Comment: Note that the intervals are not all the uncountable subsets of $\mathbb R$. An example of an uncountable subset of $\mathbb R$ that is not an interval is the set of irrational numbers, $\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Yes, I make a mistake. I mean U is the union of the open intervals. "all the uncountable sets" is not clearly enough.

Comment: Actually, I post my questions as a picture in the next comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean intervals of the reals, the union of all the open intervals, is equal to $\mathbb R$ itself. Therefore this union has the power of the continuum $\frak c=2^{\mathbb N}$ for cardinality.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much! But how can I formally prove this statement?

Comment: What do you want to prove? That the union is equal to $\mathbb R$? This is almost immediate as $\mathbb R$ itself is already an interval. Or that the cardinality of $\mathbb R$ is equal to $2^{\mathbb N}$? Which is also quite clear using dyadic development of the reals.

Answer (score 0):

In your particular question the answer is 
2^No
You may use the following steps

1. Every interval has cardinality as 2^No
2. Your Uncountable union will be contained in the Space of real numbers
3. Cardinality of the set of Real numbers is 2^No

I hope it helps.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thanks, it's very helpful! But how to formally prove this? I mean, how to show that the union of all the open intervals which have the rational endpoints is contained in the real numbers and their cardinality is c?